# Quartz says Cannot instantiate type which has no empty constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac, quartz.net

I am using latest version of Quartz.net and I am also using Autofac. I am currently seeing that my Quartz job doesn't get triggered. The error that I am getting is:

> System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate type which has no empty constructor

Now I believe I had this working before and could be the result of package upgrades for either autofac or quartz. However not sure.

My IOC container is configured like this:

```cs
    builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule());
    builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacJobsModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
    builder.RegisterModule(new QuartzAutofacFactoryModule(MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag.ToString()));

    builder.RegisterType<JobScheduler>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();

    var container = builder.Build();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag))
    {
        var scheduler = scope.Resolve<JobScheduler>();
        scheduler.Start();
    }
```

My job scheduler:

```cs
    public class JobScheduler
    {
        public JobScheduler(IScheduler scheduler)
        {
            _scheduler = scheduler;
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            var job = JobBuilder.Create<SomeJob>()
                .WithIdentity("MyJob", "MyJobGroup")
                .Build();

            var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("MyJobTrigger", "MyJobGroup")
                .StartAt(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(1))
                .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                    .WithIntervalInMinutes(2)
                    .RepeatForever()
                    .WithMisfireHandlingInstructionNextWithRemainingCount()
                    )
                .Build();

            _scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

            _scheduler.Start();
        }
    }
```

and my job is:

```cs
    public class SomeJob: IJob
    {
       public ISomedependency _dependency;
       public SomeJob(ISomedependency dependency)
       {
          _dependency = dependency;
       }

        public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
             await _dependency.DoWork();
        }
    }
```

Please keep in mind that potentially I can create a parameterless constructor for `SomeJob` but then I won't be able to use the `_dependency` to do the work.

Can someone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be with the either Quartz or Autofac.Extras.Quartz. Will report this on github. Please see screenshot.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnIry.png)